# Does MongoDB use a combination of indexes to narrow docs to scan?

Tags: mongodb, search, indexing

I know about index intersection, but it is not clear to me from the docs if the following scenario will be efficient:

I have documents that are very different from one another, all in one collection. Each document "schema" has one or many instances with different values, potentially hundreds of thousand values. I use a hash value to identify the record schema, and then other fields to search specific documents.

So for example, I got the following entries in the collection:

```
 {
    type: "ABC",
    details: { model: "14Q3", manufacturer: "M1 Corporation" },
    stock: [ { size: "M", qty: 50 } ],
    category: "clothing"
  },
  {
    item: "ABC",
    details: { model: "14Q3", manufacturer: "ABC Company" },
    stock: [ { size: "S", qty: 5 }, { size: "M", qty: 5 }, { size: "L", qty: 1 } ],
    category: "clothing"
  },
  {
    type: "XYZ",
    message: "a generic text message",
    date: [ "tag1", "tag2" , "tag3" ],
    category: "houseware",
    age: 12,
  }
  ...
```

When querying, I plan to use the type to narrow down the docs to search, then other indexed fields to search.

Will MongoDB be able to perform these queries taking advantage of the different indexed covering the fields I'm searching for?

Also, if I include the indexed `type` field in the search along with a non-indexed field, will it scan all docs or take advantage of the `type` field index to narrow, and only then scan those docs for the other criteria?

I'm on MongoDB 2.6.6.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and no. It will not use combination of indexes, but You can create compound indexes.

To simplify, for example if You will have collection:

```
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("549d0b5bde6b4daa2e1f1859"), "name" : "Adam", "age" : 15 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("549d0b70de6b4daa2e1f185a"), "name" : "John", "hobby" : "skiing" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("549d0b96de6b4daa2e1f185b"), "name" : "Barbara", "occupation" : "student" }
```

and then create compound indexes with name and each specific value:

```
db.test.ensureIndex({name: 1, age: 1})
db.test.ensureIndex({name: 1, hobby: 1})
db.test.ensureIndex({name: 1, occupation: 1})
```

and then You will try to find specific document:

```
> db.test.find({name: "Adam", age: 15}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor name_1_age_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1,
    "nscanned" : 1,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 2,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 2,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "name" : [
            [
                "Adam",
                "Adam"
            ]
        ],
        "age" : [
            [
                15,
                15
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "CBS:27017",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

You will see, that it used proper index, and, scanned only one document to find it.
Use the `explain()` command to check each query used index, search documents, and search time. It helps understanding mongodb a lot!

More info about indexes: [indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/)
and explain(): [explain](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/)

You can also set `sparse` index, that will reference only files containing specific field, but have also few more differences. More info about sparse indexes: [sparse indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-sparse/)